# Fixing a generic filter function in scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to code a filter function in scala and am not sure what the problem is here. I think I am taking the wrong approach to it as we have defined the List ourselves instead of using the standard library. But I get the same error every time. Just need help figuring out this error

```
sealed trait List[+A]
case object Empty extends List[Nothing]
case class Cons[A]( x : A, xs : List[A]) extends List[A]

def filter[A](f: A => Boolean, list: List[A]): List[A] =
for { 
    x <- list
    if (f(x)) 
} yield x

<console>:93: error: value filter is not a member of List[A]
   x <- list
```

Comment: I think I need to use a recursive approach with pattern matching when using a user defined list type

Comment: Yes you are right that you will need a recursion and pattern matching, but this question will be closed as a duplicate of the previous one. So, I will leave an answer on your previous question expanding what was the problem and the solution.

Comment: thank you sorry I will delete this duplicate question

Comment: would very much appreciate helping with the solution because I am stuck @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez